# updating text with timer and mediaplayer in android

Tags: android

hi guys i want to update my text while my mediaplayer is playing

```
     new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {

             running.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
             TextOfMaxValue.setText(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

         }

     }, 0, 1000);
```

and when i use settext inside my timer  like my code above my app crashes and do not start

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {

             running.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

         }

     }, 0, 1000);
```

it works well with the code above but i want to update my text too .

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a `String` argument to your `TextView`, not an `int`.

Use:

```
String durationText = String.valueOf(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
TextOfMaxValue.setText(durationText);
```

Comment: Post your logcat into the question. What I pointed out was an obvious error in your code, but it seems there are more mistakes.